# Zoom Pan images with d3.js

Tags: image, d3.js, html5-canvas, zooming

Hi I am trying to do zoom and pan on some images. I've got the example from this link: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3681006 the main difference there is that they drawing shapes not images. Here is a the script, what I've done

https://jsfiddle.net/t1gqg1m6/1/

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var randomX = d3.random.normal(width / 2, 80),
    randomY = d3.random.normal(height / 2, 80);

var data = d3.range(2000).map(function() {
  return [
    randomX(),
    randomY()
  ];
});

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, width])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, height])
    .range([height, 0]);

var canvas = d3.select("canvas")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).y(y).scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom))
  .node().getContext("2d");

function zoom() {
  canvas.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  draw();
}

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    function draw(){
    for(var i=0;i<=500;i+=50){
        canvas.drawImage(img, i, 10, 50, 40);
    }
  }
  draw();
}

img.src = "http://static.dnaindia.com/sites/default/files/styles/half/public/2016/04/02/444652-google-photos-emoji-google-image-search-using-emoji-coolkengzz-shutterstock.jpg?itok=b1lBccFF";
```

if some one can help would be great. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your draw function global, so that it can be called from zoom function and also from the image onload function.

```
function draw() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 500; i += 50) {
    canvas.drawImage(img, x(i), 10, 50, 40);
  }
}
```

Next instead of:

```
canvas.drawImage(img, i, 10, 50, 40);
```

it should have been:

```
canvas.drawImage(img, x(i), 10, 50, 40);
```

so that the zoom/pan calculates the new position correctly.

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/anbo2u3v/)

Comment: TY for the this quick answer. Hm that's strange. This fixed the dragging part but the images are not zooming now they're going out of each other. My idea was to zoom the actual images as they stay together, maybe I did pick up the wrong example.

Comment: yeh wrong example if you want it to become big then you should be using geometric zooming and not symmetric zooming example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680958